# UWP cannot connect to local Socket.IO server

Tags: c#, .net, socket.io, uwp

I have an UWP application which is connecting to a Socket.IO server. When debugging I like it to be a local server, but I can't get it to connect it. I use the [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/) library, and it works well if I have to connect to an external server, but I can't connect to the local one.

I'm aware that on default UWP apps forbids connecting to local servers, I think it's called loopback, but I'm also tried to go around that by using this tool:
http://loopback.codeplex.com/
However, It didn't helped.

Any help is much appreciated, and thanks in advance! : )

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you didn't enable the relevant capability in your project. Please open the **manifest** of your app can select the **Capabilitie**s label and check the **Private Networks (Client & Server)** on the left.

This capability's name is "privateNetworkClientServe", this capability provides inbound and outbound access to home and work networks through the firewall.

For more info about capabilities, you can refer to [App capability declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).

**Update:**

Due to loopback restrictions enforced by network isolation policy, when use TCP protocol, server and client must run on separate machines for them to be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the question, but I checked that part in manifest. So the Private Networks Capability is checked in the project, but I still can't connect to the local server, while I can connect to it with a Console-application.

Comment: @monutam91, Is that your port for this is occupied by other connection like your console app? I met this problem once, have a try to disconnect all the connections and connect only with your UWP app again?

Comment: @monutam91, are you using UDP protocol or TCP protocol? I just updated my answer, you can take a look.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Will  SocketIoClientDotNet work on HoloLens?

Comment: Setting the Capabilities helped me!